# SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2019 Migration with SP Designer Workflows and Infopath

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, infopath, designer-workflow, 2019

We are planning to move the SharePoint 2010 environment to SharePoint 2019 using the content database attach method. We are having SharePoint 2010 designer workflows, OOTB workflows and Infopath forms in SP2010.

What is the best practice to migrate to the above-mentioned objects?

After the migration in SharePoint 2019 modern list/libraries, I will add an item into any workflow associated list, Will it trigger the designer workflow or not?

Answer (score 2):

As far as SharePoint content database migration is concerned using the detach and attach method it will migrate everything - all designer workflows along with infopath forms. And we can not migrate directly from SharePoint 2010 to 2019. The sequence is 2010->2013->2016 ->2019

**Few key points to remember:**

- Complete all running workflows in SharePoint 2010 before migration.
- Prepare an inventory for all infopath forms in SharePoint 2010.
- Prepare an inventory for all data connection used in the infopath
  forms.
- After migrating to SP2019 immediately change the data connection url to new URL(SP 2019 data connection URL).
- Then open all the infopath form which we have generated from SP2010.

**How to get all infopath forms?**

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint") > $null 

function global:Get-SPSite($url){ 

    return new-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($url) 

} 

#Get the web application 

$WebAppURL= "<Web Application URL>" 

$SiteColletion = Get-SPSite($WebAppURL) 

$WebApp = $SiteColletion.WebApplication 



#Write the CSV header 

"Site Collection `t Site `t List Name `t List Url `t Docs Count `t Last Modified `t WF Count `t Live WF `t Live WF Names `t Form Template" > c:\temp\InfoPathLibs.csv 



#Loop through all site collections of the web app 

    foreach ($site in $WebApp.Sites) 

    { 

       # get the collection of webs 

       foreach($web in $site.AllWebs) 

        { 

            write-host "Scaning Site" $web.title "@" $web.URL 

               foreach($list in $web.lists) 

               { 

                   if( $list.BaseType -eq "DocumentLibrary" -and $list.BaseTemplate -eq "XMLForm") 

       { 

                  $listModDate = $list.LastItemModifiedDate.ToShortDateString() 

                $listTemplate = $list.ServerRelativeDocumentTemplateUrl 

                  $listWorkflowCount = $list.WorkflowAssociations.Count 

                $listLiveWorkflowCount = 0 

                $listLiveWorkflows = "" 



                foreach ($wf in $list.WorkflowAssociations) 

        { 

                    if ($wf.Enabled) 

         { 

                        $listLiveWorkflowCount++ 

                        if ($listLiveWorkflows.Length -gt 0) 

         { 

                            $listLiveWorkflows = "$listLiveWorkflows, $($wf.Name)" 

                        } 

                        else  

         { 

                            $listLiveWorkflows = $wf.Name 

                        } 

                     } 

                 } 

       #Write data to CSV File 

                   $site.RootWeb.Title +"`t" + $web.Title +"`t" + $list.title +"`t" + $Web.Url + "/" + $List.RootFolder.Url  +"`t" + $list.ItemCount +"`t" + $listModDate +"`t"  

+ $listWorkflowCount +"`t" + $listLiveWorkflowCount +"`t" + $listLiveWorkflows +"`t" + $listTemplate >> c:\temp\InfoPathLibs.csv 

             } 

               } 

        } 

    } 



#Dispose of the site object 

$siteColletion.Dispose() 

Write-host  "Report Generated at c:\temp\InfoPathLibs.csv" -foregroundcolor green
```

**Reference URL:**

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Find-all-lists-that-have-dc9a0420

**Note:**

Sometimes, if we change the data connection correctly from the new environment, still we will get the data connection error. Then we need to disable the **loopback** in the registry. And also we need to verify the **layout** path in the data connection because layout path in SP2010 and SP2019 is different.

Comment: Thanks for your kind response.

Comment: Hi @karthikeyan Ganesan, welcome and it is my pleasure... if this helps you could please mark this as answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

Since you're performing a database-attach upgrade, you don't need to do anything special with those objects since they're part of the database.

As for modern lists/libraries, it depends on what you've done with them (e.g. if you've used a customized form via InfoPath, the list will render in classic mode). However, workflows will continue to run on them as expected.

Comment: Here the question is SharePoint 2010 platform workflows will work in the SP2019?. 
If it will work, we need to republish the workflow?

Comment: As I stated, your WFs will upgrade as-is. No extra work needs to be done for them.